# Sublime Text: Dreamweaver like template functionality?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

One thing i like about dreamweaver was its template (.dwt files) functionality, in which if we create any .html file from such template, any changing afterwards in those templates would also be applicable in all such .html files.

I wanted to know if there is any such functionality/extension available for sublime text editor?

Comment: I've never seen a plugin for ST that does that, but you could write one using their package API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got such functionality by using `Gulp` build system together with this extension: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include

This extension allows PHP like file include commands in .html files. For example we can use `@@include('header.html')` in multiple files and create a separate `header.html` file, thus any change in `header.html` would apply in all those files which've the above include command. Such plugins are also available for `Grunt` build system. However i personally prefer `Gulp` over `Grunt`.

An introduction about gulp can be found here: http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-gulp-js/